# Error Occurring From Pow Function in C

Tags: c

I have included the math.h header file.

If I do something like

```
   float var = pow(2, 3)
```

it complies and there aren't any errors. But if I try something like

```
float var2 = 5;
float var = pow(var2, 2)
```

it doesn't compile and gives me the error

```
undefined reference to `pow' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not very familiar with c, but I have no idea why this is happening, as it is fine without using a variable. It's like if I use a variable in the pow function, it gives me this error. I am using Xubuntu and then run the command

```
"cc -g -std=c99 myfile.c
```

to compile the program.

Comment: compile with the flag `-lm` like this:gcc yours.c -lm -o yours

Comment: @mb84 Totally wrong and unhelpful. Did you even read the question? do you understand what happens to an `int` when passed to a function expecting a `float`?

Comment: @H2CO3 I know. I just confound it with unresolved overload, but its not the case, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link in the math library, which you need for the `pow()` function, compile with this switch added:

```
gcc -g -std=c99 myfile.c -lm
```